# Продлить жизнь объекта

Tags: c++

Есть некоторый Handler по обработке массивов данных

```
using Image = std::vector<char>;
using Images = std::vector<Image>;

class Handler : public std::enable_shared_from_this<Handler>
{
public:
    Handler(const std::shared_ptr<Sender>& sender)
        : m_sender(sender){}
        
    ~Handler() = default;

    void handleData(Images images)
    {
        auto asyncSend = std::bind(&Handler::makeMessage, this,
                               std::placeholders::_1,
                               std::placeholders::_2);

        AsioPool::run(std::move(asyncSend), std::move(images), shared_from_this());
    }

private:
    void makeMessage(Images images, std::shared_ptr<Handler> self)
    {
        Image result;
        for (const auto& image : images)
        {
            // Тяжелые вычисления
        }        
        m_sender->send(std::move(result));
    }
    
private:
    std::shared_ptr<Sender> m_sender;
};
```

в одном из потоков создается много этих Handler-ов

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Handler> handlers;
for (...)
    handlers.emplace_back(std::make_shared<Handler>(sender_ptr));
```

Другой поток через Handler-ы обрабатывает данные

```
for (auto& handler : handlers)
    handler->handleData(std::move(images));
```

Третий поток, может удалить эти Handler-ы

```
handlers.clear();
```

В результате, в момент, когда AsioPool::run(...) дойдет до выполнения Handler::makeMessage самого объекта может уже не существовать, если не передавать в метод shared_from_this().
AsioPool::run(...) это обертка над бустовым asio, работает по принципу "отдал и забыл".

Какие есть еще методы продлить жизнь объекту, без передачи своего shared_ptr ?

Comment: А чем руководствуется поток, удаляя объекты?

Comment: и зачем вам несколько хэндлеров в одном потоке? Все равно сможет работать только одни за раз

Comment: если shared_ptr почему то не подходит, можно создать свою обертку, которая будет хранить внутри себя объект и контролировать его жизнь. Но боюсь получится тот же shared_ptr, но со своими багами. С другой стороны в бусте есть  [intrusive_ptr](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/smart_ptr/intrusive_ptr.html)  - возможно, это то, что нужно.

Comment: > А чем руководствуется поток, удаляя объекты?
Отключился сетевой клиент, например

> и зачем вам несколько хэндлеров в одном потоке? Все равно сможет работать только одни за раз 

Объект, содержащий хендлеры, могут дергать разные потоки, здесь довольно условно приведен код.

> если shared_ptr почему то не подходит, можно создать свою обертку, которая будет хранить внутри себя объект и контролировать его жизнь.

Он не то чтобы не подходит, просто мне кажется, что это небольшой оверхед в данном месте.

Comment: если shared_ptr оверхед, тогда придумайте свой способ синхронизации, либо клиенты, которые отключились, ставятся на ожидание. Ещё не факт, где будет оверхед. Вначале нужно написать работающее приложение, а потом уже искать оверхеды

Comment: KoVadim я собственно поэтому и спросил здесь совета, какие есть методы продления жизни в данном случае. Приложение уже работает, теперь нужно максимально оптимизировать, а свой синхронизатор, это будет дополнительный объект со своей логикой и еще не известно, какой он оверхед привнесет.

Comment: а с какой целью пытаетесь оптимизировать? медленно работает? выедает больше памяти, чем idea? пользователи жалуются?

Comment: С целью использовать как можно меньше ресурсов, т.к. это малая и далеко не основная часть того что должно делать приложение, и если здесь будет оверхед, тогда он скажется и на остальном быстродействии. В общем нужны минимальные, практически незаметные затраты в данном месте, т.к. оно промежуточное для основного взаимодействия приложения.

Comment: ага, то есть  просто червячок оптимизации. Это нормально. Перед подобными оптимизациями померяйте, а сколько оно реально тратит, какой оверхед. Как только сможете его посчитать - сразу поймете, как можно "оптимизировать" У меня было такое, только мне говорили, что мое приложение нужно оптимизировать. А потом я открыл top (диспетчер задач) и там не было моей программы. Точнее, она была, но далеко-далеко внизу. На том и успокоились. Если ещё есть сомнения, перепишите свою программу на чем то новомодном - java или расте и сравните. И все сомнения сразу развеются.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/coroutines